# Batch script to List all Folders and subfolders (Folders contains Millions of files)

Tags: batch-file, dir

I'm trying to list all Folders and subFolders in a specific path, While the SubFolders contains a huge amount of dat files (~Millions).
When Using: `for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /A-D-H-S /B /S "f:\Data\*.dat"') do (SET OF COMMANDS)` The `(/S)` switch **stuck** the run due to the huge files amount in `f:\Data` SubFolders.
Is there a way to list all SubFolders despite the files amount?
Or how can I do the command `Dir /ad` to every Folder/subfolder and send to text file without using `\S` Switch in case of using a `for` loop?

Comment: Getting rid of the first `-` in `/A-D-H-S` (so that it's `/AD-H-S`) will only list subdirectories, but I'm not sure how well it will work if there's as much data as you say there is.

Comment: `dir /b /s /a:d` - Also had the same stuck problem due to '/s' SubFolders Switch.

Comment: How about `for /r /d %%I in (*) do ( stuff with each directory )`?

Comment: @rojo - The same result, it stuck again.

Comment: If I do in the command line: `Dir /ad` in each directory it works fine without any delay!